# Existence of a function in one real variable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x)) \neq x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and

for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = f(a) \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = a \, ?$$

Comment: Do you mean, for all $x$, $f(f(x))\neq x$, or, there exists $x$ such that $f(f(x))\neq x$?

Comment: You can start by considering a function which is discontinuous everywhere, instead of a function which is continuous at at least one point $a$. Because if you start with a continuous $f$, then you can put the limit inside $f$, and get $f\left(f\left(a\right)\right)=a$.

Comment: I mean $f(f(x)) \neq x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ that map each nontrivial interval onto $\mathbb R$, like the [Conway base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function).  If $f$ is such a function, then for each $a\in\mathbb R$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $f(a)$ such that $f(x_n)=a$ for all $n$.

For such $f$, $f\circ f$ is not the identity function.  However, this does not imply that there is no $x$ such that $f(f(x))=x$, so in light of the edit this may not answer the question.  I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it true that for such a function $f$
$$
f(f(x)) \neq x
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Pasta: You're welcome. Not necessarily; this answer was from before you added quantification of $x$.  I made a guess about what is meant and I was wrong.  I don't know how to fix it.